# pmode in MATLAB 2013a is not working

Tags: macos, matlab, parallel-processing

pmode was working after installation, but I couldn't run my script on it. I would get the following error:

```
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nodisplay and

-noFigureWindows startup options. For more information, see "Changes to

-nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options" in the MATLAB Release Notes.

To view the release note in your system browser, run

web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br5ktrh-3',

'-browser')
```

After searching for a while, I just tried to do it again. Without having changed anything. Now pmode is not even starting. I get the following error:

```
pmode start Error using initclient (line 37) Java exception occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:286)   at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:321)

Error in distcomp/schema (line 11) initclient;

Error in parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient (line 17)
            obj.UserName = distcomp.pGetDefaultUsername();

Error in parallel.internal.pool.SessionManager>iGetOrSetInteractiveObject (line 61)
                conn = parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient();

Error in parallel.internal.pool.SessionManager.getSessionObject (line 13)
            s = iGetOrSetInteractiveObject( 'create' );

Error in pmode (line 80)
    client = parallel.internal.pool.SessionManager.getSessionObject();
```

I am using MATLAB 2013a on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Update: I tried to reset my MATLAB using this instructions: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1093

Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for both questions:
1) It is not possible to run any gui with `pmode`, so it is necessary to remove everything like `uigetfile`.

2) There is a bug in the 2013a version with Java on Mac. A possible work around is:

1. Open Matlab
2. Before doing anything, push the parallel computing button and select Manage Cluster Profiles
3. Just close this window again
4. Now you can use `pmode`, `matlabpool`, etc

I patch is coming available but is not working for everybody.